# PHP usort in custom order

Tags: php, usort

I am trying to sort array, lets say :

`['qwe',12,'*', 324, '$we']`, but I want it to sort : first numbers, then special characters and letters at last.

I know that I have to use `usort()`, but am not sure how to write callback function to achieve what I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Pay special attention to this sentence from the manual: `The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.` Your callback, therefore, must say that all numbers are less than special characters and that those are less than letters.

Comment: The task is insufficiently described. For example, how are strings like "abc1" classified? The classification applies to every character in a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sort the elements in the array, and not the characters within the elements themselves, you could use the following, ugly but functional, solution:

```
$array = ['qwe',12,'*', 324, '$we'];

$nums = $spec = $letters = array();

foreach ($array as $i) {
    if (is_numeric($i)) {
        array_push($nums, $i); 
    } 
    else if (ctype_alpha($i)) {
        array_push($letters, $i);
    }
    else if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $i)) {
        array_push($spec, $i);
    }
}
 
sort($nums);
sort($letters);
sort($spec);

$sorted = array_merge($nums,$spec,$letters);

var_dump($sorted);
```

This will iterate through your initial array and add each item to a different array, basing on its type (regex used to detect symbols). Then the single arrays are alphabetically sorted, and merged in the order of your liking.

The above code will output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(12)
  [1]=>
  int(324)
  [2]=>
  string(3) "$we"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "*"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "qwe"
}
```